# ASP.NET Core API with authorization prompts for sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, authorize-attribute, api-authorization, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

We are using Windows Authentication on one endpoint in our C#/ASPNet Core 3.1 API. It is configured like:

Startup.ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

Startup.Configure():

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

and the endpoint on which we require authentication has the [Authorize] attribute on the Post method in the controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("somewhere"]
public IActionResult Post() { ... }
```

In Chrome, I am prompted for credentials and then allowed to use the endpoint on subsequent requests (even if I cancel the prompt).

How to prevent the prompt?

Comment: See if this helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-certificate-authentication-in-custom-web-proxies

Comment: I don't think this is for Windows authentication? Sorry, I updated my question to add that it's windows auth.

Comment: The are more than one type of window authorization,  You do not want a username/password to be used.  For default authentication the user must have the same account on both local and remote machines.  So both local and remote have to share the same password server.  You can avoid the prompt by using a certificate with TLS authentication.  The windows authentication mode can be setup to use a certificate.  That is the link I provided.